# tabs pager application crashed with onbackpress button

Tags: android

I'm using the sample Google provides, FragmentTabsPager to work with tabs in my application. and i add the method onbackpress to return to the first activity but this method crashed my application when i press the back button or also the home button that i didn't override it

```
   @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
        }
     @Override
     public void onBackPressed()
      {
         //call intent
    Intent i = new Intent(this,home.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();


      }
```

it return Null pointer exception at the method onSaveInstanceState

so can anyone help with it thx for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved it by instantiate each fragment in my application and  put something into the bundle of each one of these fragement

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("bla2", 0);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```